# color transition on page load in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition

I have some global colors set on links and transitions set on the color:

```
a {
  color: blue;
  transition: color 300ms linear; }
```

Now, later on in my code I have some more specific styling on links in the nav:

```
nav a { color: red; }
nav a:hover { color: black; }
```

The HTML simply looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**The following works as expected:**

- Links in the nav inherit the color transition
- When links in the nav are hovered, their color changes with a smooth transition

**The issue is:**
When the page loads in Chrome, the link starts with either a default color, or the global link color I set (I'm not sure which), then the transition immediately kicks in and the link changes to the correct color.

The issue seems specific to Google Chrome. I tried to recreate the issue in JSfiddle but it worked fine in the fiddle.

Is there a way to stop the transition happening on page load?

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: It's [impossible to recreate](http://jsfiddle.net/aHVSs/) just using the code provided. Please provide enough code to reproduce your issue. Also, what's wrong with moving the `nav a` before the `a`? It has a higher specificity so it doesn't matter which is after

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur The issue could not be recreated in a fiddle.

Comment: I've edited my question to be a little more specific and clear. The issue seems to only happen in Google Chrome. I'm running version 36.

Comment: This seems to be a bug that depends on the markup. I have a page with this problem but cannot reproduce in a simpler version. Currently running version 40. Firefox is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, which I was fine with until sometimes I noticed that the initial transition wouldn't start, leaving an unintentional color on my button.

Then, I found this post on css-tricks, which fixed my problem.

http://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

The idea is that you disable all animations until the dom is loaded. If you're using Angular, you can remove the class with ng-init or any directive really.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes that's not a bad idea! Thanks for finding the link. It's a shame some browsers do this by default - it doesn't make sense seeing as it's trying to transition to a state you've told it to be a default state for the element and so should obviously be the first version you see of it.

Comment: The whole point of CSS transitions is to be able to animate without JavaScript. This solution is a very unfortunate hack.

Comment: For me not working with combination with scrollscpy (BS4), but good trick.

Answer (score -1):

Well, i researched about how to set condition on elements parent, and the relative selectors are `:has()`, `:parent`, `:not()`, but none of them can solve the problem.
So i think, you can't find a clean solution. (i will be happy if i'm wrong)
But as an alternative solution, i have 2 idea!

First, put the `transition` in hover state.
In this case you won't see any transition on css overwriting, like this:

```
a:hover { 
    transition: all 1s; //with venders
    color: #666; 
}

nav a:hover { 
    transition: all 1s; //with venders
    color: #AAA; 
}
```

Second, you can put class on your `<a></a>` tags, and select them, like:

```
a.parentIsNotNav {
    ...
}

a.prentIsNav {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The suggested solution will not work as it will only transition from the older color to the new color, not the opposite way

Comment: @ZachSaucier; first, there was 2 idea, then, in the first idea after it solve your page loading isue, you can simply add the transition to main scope by js in onload(). i said they are not the clean solution you're looking for, they are alternative!

Comment: @MeTe-30 Thanks for your help but this isn't the solution I was looking for. Your first solution will mean link colors do not transition back to their original state when hovering finishes, which essentially is changing the effect. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve in your second idea, but I can't see how that would work.